# Consulta utilizado count PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Tenho uma query aonde preciso que ela me retornar os valores incluído zero aonde está sendo passado no `count` a tabela `cdado.cod_andamento_dado` mesmo retirado o nome da tabela e passado `count (*)` não está me trazendo valores com número zero

```
SELECT
   Now() AS "time",
   Upper(nom_cliente) || ' - ' || conf.sistema || '-' || conf.dsc_estado || ')' AS "nome cliente",
   Count(cdado.cod_andamento_dado) AS "quantidade" 
FROM
   situacao.andamento_configuracao conf 
   INNER JOIN
      adm.cliente cli 
      ON cli.cod_cliente = conf.cod_cliente 
   LEFT JOIN
      situacao.andamento_dado cdado 
      ON conf.cod_andamento_configuracao = cdado.cod_andamento_configuracao 
WHERE
   cli.ind_status_registro = true 
   AND conf.ind_status_registro = true 
   AND 
   (
      cdado.dat_inclusao > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '02 days')
   )
   AND cli.cod_cliente = 50 
GROUP BY
   1,
   2 
ORDER BY
   3,
   2 ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Se não existe esses valores entre as tabelas provavelmente ele não ira contar, ou ira contar os nulos. No caso como você esta passando o argumento dentro de `COUNT` ele não ira contar nulos.

Você pode tentar

```
COUNT(DISTINCT("column")) + (CASE bool_or("column" IS NULL) WHEN true THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Nesse caso ele deve transformar nulos em 1 e contar para você, ou você pode tentar:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN column IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Esse ultimo caso também vai gerar uma coluna que vai somar apenas caso o valor seja nulo.